# how to convert cv::Mat to cv::Matx33f

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` that I want to convert into a `cv::Matx33f`. I try to do it like this:

```
cv::Mat m;
cv::Matx33f m33;
.........
m33 = m;
```

but all the data gets lost! Any idea how to do this ?

**UPDATE** 
here is a part of the code which causes my problem :

```
cv::Point2f Order::warpPoint(cv::Point2f pTmp){
    cv::Matx33f warp = this->getTransMatrix() ; // the getter gives a cv::Mat back 
    transformMatrix.copyTo(warp); // because the first method didn't work, I tried to use the copyto function 

    // and the last try was 
    warp = cv::Matx33f(transformationMatrix); // and waro still 0 
    cv::Point3f  warpPoint = cv::Matx33f(transformMatrix)*pTmp;
    cv::Point2f result(warpPoint.x, warpPoint.y);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html says:

"If you need to do some operation on Matx that is not implemented, it is easy to convert the matrix to Mat and backwards."

```
Matx33f m(1, 2, 3,
          4, 5, 6,
          7, 8, 9);
cout << sum(Mat(m*m.t())) << endl;
```

Comment: This is working for me correctly:
Matx33f m(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
Mat x = Mat(m);
std::cout << x;

Comment: to be honest I don't get why it doesn't work here I get the frame from an other class a it should work fine, because I wrote a simple main function with it and it did work :)( , but thanks a lot for answer ! I think it's correct !

Comment: @Engine This shows converting from Matx to Mat, but how can you easily convert Mat to Matx?

Comment: @Eruditass sorry can't remember anymore

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (converting `cv::Mat` to `cv::Matx`).

Answer (score 11):

To convert from Mat to Matx, one can use the data pointer. For example,

```
cv::Mat m; // assume we know it is CV_32F type, and its size is 3x3

cv::Matx33f m33((float*)m.ptr());
```

This should do the job, assuming continuous memory in m. You can check it by:

```
std::cout << "m " << m << std::endl;

std::cout << "m33 " << m33 << std::endl;
```

Comment: It is better to use  m.clone().ptr() instead of  m.ptr(). This way it will work even if original matrix m was not continuous in memory.

Comment: this converts a uchar * to a float *? how is that ok?

Comment: I am with @simplename. When accessing and casting the pointer like this, type safety is indeed not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that the question is old, but this should also work:

```
auto m33 = Matx33f(m.at<float>(0, 0), m.at<float>(0, 1), m.at<float>(0, 2),
                   m.at<float>(1, 0), m.at<float>(1, 1), m.at<float>(1, 2),
                   m.at<float>(2, 0), m.at<float>(2, 1), m.at<float>(2, 2));
```

Comment: While this does indeed work, it is rather cumbersome to write. I expect the conversion to be available without explicit element access.

Answer (score 0):

There are now special conversion operators available in cv::Mat class for both ways:

```
cv::Mat {
    template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> operator Matx<_Tp, m, n>() const;
}

        cv::Mat tM = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(uvp, svp);
        auto ttM = cv::Matx33f(tM);
        ...
        tM = cv::Mat(ttM);
```

Comment: where did you find this conversion?

Comment: @simplename It has been around for [more thant 10 years](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blame/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L1663), but it is [not well documented](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a75b1b5424cf014f00d8f06ba1818a5d8).