# How to convert opencv Matx to Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking to convert a `cv::Matx44d` to a `cv::Mat` of type `double` and size `rows = cols = 4`

I've seen this answer that talks about the reverse: [how to convert cv::Mat to cv::Matx33f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919814/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-cvmatx33f)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `Mat` ctor that does this:

```
template<typename _Tp , int m, int n>
cv::Mat::Mat(const Matx< _Tp, m, n > & mtx, bool copyData = true)
```